# Regular Expression to Extract Expression from Function?

Tags: python, regex

Here are some sample inputs:

```
Fxfu(x1,Y,n<X+Y)

Fxfu(x1,Y(n,A,B),Z(n,A,B)+M(n,A,B)<n)

Fxfu(x1,Y(n),Z(n)^M(n)<X+Y)

Fxfu(x1,(n,A,B),Z(n)^M(n)<T(n,A,B))
```

and I want their corresponding outputs to be:

```
n<X+Y

Z(n,A,B)+M(n,A,B)<n

Z(n)^M(n)<X+Y

Z(n)^M(n)<T(n,A,B)
```

I have written the following code

```
find=regex.compile(r'(Fxfu\(x\d+[,]([Y]\((.*)\)[,]))|Fxfu\(x\d+[,]([Y][,])')
    group = find.search(expression)
    print expression.replace(group.group(0),"")
```

Any better way to do the above so that I can extract all the parameter in array as follows

```
[x1,Y,n<X+Y]
[x1,Y(n,A,B),Z(n,A,B)+M(n,A,B)<n]
[x1,Y(n),Z(n)^M(n)<X+Y]
[x1,(n,A,B),Z(n)^M(n)<T(n,A,B)]
```

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question earlier?

Comment: Why do you write `[F][x][f][u]` instead of just `Fxfu`?

Comment: Regular expressions are not generally good for parsing recursive patterns like this. You need to use a recursive descent parser.

Comment: Yes, one of my friends ask ...He misses few things thanks a lot for suggestion I will try that

Comment: I have change [F][x][f][u] to Fxfu..Thanks a lot

Comment: You don't really need a full-blown recursive descent parser, but regexes are a bad match (ho ho) for counting parentheses (more specifically: "real" regexes cannot do it, period, extended regexes can but are ill-suited for the task). You can extract the part you need in a single pass, by keeping a count of open/closed parentheses and commas.

Comment: If parentheses can be nested arbitrarily deep, then regular expressions can't help you.  _n_ open-parens followed by _n_ close-parens is a form of palindrome, and [regexes can't match arbitrary palindromes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome#Computation_theory).  If the parts of the input you skip over never have more than one pair of parens per term (parameter?  function call?), then you _could_ use a regex to skip past them, and then a capturing group to grab everything except the last `')'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regexes are ill-suited for the task, as explained in the comments; however, you can easily solve the problem in a single pass by counting the parentheses:

```
def extract_args(expr):
    paren = 0
    start = 0
    ret = []
    for i, c in enumerate(expr):
        if c=='(':
            paren+=1
            if paren==1:
                start=i+1
        elif c==')':
            if paren==1 and start:
                ret.append(expr[start: i]) 
            paren-=1
        elif c==',' and paren==1:
            ret.append(expr[start:i])
            start=i+1
    return ret
```

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot for answer ..but getting error "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not tuple" for condition " elif c==',' and paren==1:"

Comment: @Tom: there was a similar error in a previous revision of my answer, the current one [should be ok](https://ideone.com/lyyu0r).